# lualatex not available in Debian Wheezy

Tags: luatex, debian

I want to use `lualatex`for compiling Latex document based on Luatex. I have installed those packages: *luatex, texlive-binaries, texlive-luatex* …but no `lualatex`binary can be found. What did I miss?

Comment: Probably best to ask Debian? Do you have `texlive-full`? But, really, this is a matter of how Debian packages TeX Live (how they cut and slice it) and configure it, which you just have to find out from Debian resources. If you install from upstream, it is different and there will be lots of people here who know where things are etc. I'd recommend that, but I understand that many people prefer to stick to their distro's packages.

Answer (score 3):

I raised [this also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300125/lualatex-not-available-in-debian-wheezy)  the same on Unix StackExchange, the missing key is installation of `texlive-latex-base` package.

All in all, I had to install packages in total worth several hundreds of MByte just for successfully compiling a test Latex document with LuaLatex, unfortunately LuaLatex does not leave a smaller footprint on one's system.